# how to check for OS system date using word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I got a similar qn post for excel and was answer but it cannot work on ms word.

I wanna check for the OS date format (whether is it in "dd/mm/yyyy" or "mm/dd/yyyy")

i used the following script in excel vba, but it doesn't work in word, anyone can help?

```
    '========== Check OS Date format========
Dim OSDateFormatType As Integer
'  0 = month-day-year;   1 = day-month-year;   2 = year-month-day
If Application.International(xlDateOrder) = 0 Then
    OSDateFormatType = 0
ElseIf Application.International(xlDateOrder) = 1 Then
    OSDateFormatType = 1
ElseIf Application.International(xlDateOrder) = 2 Then
    OSDateFormatType = 2
End If
```

Comment: do you interact with excel through word vba or you need this information only in word?

Comment: I wonder why you need this. You [have solved first half of the problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx), haven't you?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use UDF (user defined function) which can be as follows:

```
Function OSDateFormatType()
    Dim tmpDate As String
    tmpDate = CStr(Replace(Replace(DateSerial(2020, 12, 31), "/", ""), "-", ""))
    If tmpDate = "12312020" Then
        OSDateFormatType = 0
    ElseIf tmpDate = "31122020" Then
        OSDateFormatType = 1
    ElseIf tmpDate = "20201231" Then
        OSDateFormatType = 2
    Else
        OSDateFormatType = "check"
    End If

End Function
```